# Why is the subsequent result from my mysql table not creating a new object in my listview?

Tags: php, android, mysql, listview, android-volley

I wanted to create a listview (simpleadapter) of each entry from my table in my database onto a new activity. But after compiling the code below, I was only able to get back the first entry.

I tried to play around by changing `int i = 0` to see if I can get the 2nd entry (which I was able to), and tried changing `response.length()` to see if changing it to "3" will display more than 1 entry (which I can't).

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-json-parsing-retrieve-from-mysql-database/) but I think his method seems out of date. I was trying to use volley I guess.

This is the result generated from my php file:

```
[ {"image_url":"https:\/\/kowhx.000webhostapp.com\/codes\/shop\/ny.png","name":"ny","price":"10.5"},
  {"image_url":"https:\/\/kowhx.000webhostapp.com\/codes\/shop\/ty.png","name":"ty","price":"11.5"}]
```

And this is my code :

```
public class MenuList extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG_NAME="name";
    private static final String TAG_PRICE="price";
    private static final String TAG_IMAGEURL="image_url";

    ListView list;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> menuList;
    RequestQueue rq;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_list);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    menuList = new ArrayList<>();
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.menuListView);
    fetch();

}



public void fetch(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String url = "https://kowhx.000webhostapp.com/codes/getMenu.php?username="+sharedPreferences.getString(Config.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF,"Not Available");
    final JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> dish = new HashMap<>();
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name = jsonObject.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String price = jsonObject.getString(TAG_PRICE);
                    String imageUrl = jsonObject.getString(TAG_IMAGEURL);

                    dish.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    dish.put(TAG_PRICE, price);
                    dish.put(TAG_IMAGEURL, imageUrl);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                menuList.add(dish);
            }
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MenuList.this, menuList, R.layout.menu_item, new String[]{TAG_NAME, TAG_PRICE, TAG_IMAGEURL}, new int[]{R.id.menuName, R.id.menuPrice, R.id.menuImage});
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
       public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

       }}
    );
    rq.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh actually it works but just that my layout is using nestedscrollview so the listview won't show more than 1 item. if i change it to relative layout everything will be solved.